# Biblatex: How to suppress same author of multiple citations?

Tags: biblatex

I need to use the features of biblatex's `verbose` citestyle but I don't want it to repeat the author's name in multiple citations by the same author (like the `authortitle-comp` option).

Currently, using the `citestyle=verbose` option, if I cite three works by "An Author" as:

```
\autocites{ANAuthor:1}{ANAuthor:2}{ANAuthor:3}
```

the output is: `"A. N. Author. 'First work' etc [full entry]; A. N. Author. 'Second work' etc [full entry]; A. N. Author. 'Third work' etc [full entry]."`

But I need to have the output: `"A. N. Author. 'First work' etc [full entry]; 'Second work' etc [full entry]; 'Third work' etc [full entry]."`

Is there any way to do this in the `verbose` style? That is, suppress the author field in multiple citations for subsequent works by the same author?

Grateful for any assistance!

---

*Update clarification*

The only way to achieve this, I think, is to make a custom `biblatex` `citestyle`. Looking at the `verbose.cbx` the relevant command is the the printing of the `bibhypertarget`, as in the commands for full and short citations:

> ```
>    \newbibmacro*{cite:full}{%  
>         printtext[bibhypertarget]{%  
>         \usedriver  
>           {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}  
>           {\thefield{entrytype}}}%  
>       \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
>
>    \newbibmacro*{cite:short}{%  
>       \printnames{labelname}%  
>       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%  
>       \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%  
>         \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
> ```

Does anyone know how to modify that to print the author field as blank when the same author appears previously in the same multicites command?

Comment: I guess this is not exactly what you want but I ask to make sure. Have you tried the style verbose-note? Also, welcome to tex.sx!

Comment: Hi, thanks, and thanks for the welcome! :-) Alas, `verbose-note` is not what I want. It doesn't solve the problem of multiple citations... I might consider implementing what it does do (ie refer back) but, that's another issue, I think...

Comment: I think it needs a combination of `authortitle-comp` feature with `verbose` style...

Comment: Comment on the edit: I tried to tweak things around, and came almost to the same conclusion. In fact, I think it would be better to create a new \usedriver macro, which would not print everything but will remove the author. Alas, It is well beyond my competencies.

Answer (score 7):

As @henrique said (in the comments), a combination of `authortitle-comp` and `verbose` should work:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article,
  author = {Arnold Author},
  title = {A journal article},
  journaltitle = {Some Journal},
  date = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19-75}
}
@book{book,
  author = {Arnold Author},
  title = {Some Book},
  editor = {Edmund Editor},
  location = {London},
  date = {2000},
  options = {useeditor=false}
}
@collection{coll,
  editor = {Arnold Author},
  title = {An edited volume},
  location = {London},
  date = {2002}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=verbose,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cite:init}{%
  \ifnumless{\value{multicitecount}}{2}
    {\global\undef\cbx@lasthash}
    {\iffieldundef{prenote}
       {}
       {\global\undef\cbx@lasthash}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:reinit}{%
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
         {\ifboolexpr{
           test {\ifuseauthor}
           and not
           test {\ifnameundef{author}}}
          {\clearname{author}}
          {\ifboolexpr{
             test {\ifuseeditor}
             and not
             test {\ifnameundef{editor}}}
            {\clearname{editor}}
            {\ifboolexpr{
               test {\ifusetranslator}
               and not
               test {\ifnameundef{translator}}}
              {\clearname{translator}}
              {}}}}
         {}%
       \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}%
  \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\ifnameundef{labelname}
        {}
        {\printnames{labelname}%
         \setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\autocites{article}{book}{coll}
\autocites{article}{book}{coll}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note that there might be problems when author and editor occur in one work (the editor will be printed before the title), but you can circuit this by adding `options = {useeditor=false}` to the respective entry.

Comment: @domwass, the first citation still prints the author's name in both references...

Comment: @henrique, you are right, I now edited my answer accordingly. The code for the full citations is a bit more complicated, since `\clearname{labelname}` is not possible, as far as I know, so that it is necessary to check if author, editor, or translator are used.

Comment: @domwass, thanks indeed for this. Unfortunately, when I run your example I get the following error `! Package biblatex Error: Bibliography macro 'cite:full:citepages' undefined.` And the output footcite in the pdf is not right either: `Arnold Author. “A
and not test
test
and not test
test
and not test
Arnold Author.
and not test
test
and not test
test
and not test
Arnold Author,
2
journal article”. In: Some Journal 6 (2006), pp. 19–75; test
Some Book. Ed. by Edmund Editor. London, 2000; test
ed. An edited volume. London, 2002.`  Is this error because I'm running biblatex 0.9a, do you think?

Comment: @MCS: Yes, the citepages option was introduced in biblatex 0.9b. (The same might be true for the `\ifboolexpr` syntax, though this is from the `etoolbox` package.) Is there any reason you are using such an old version? There have been many improvements and bugfixes since then. In the above example, you could delete the two lines which contain `citepages`. It should still work.

Comment: @domwass, thanks again for your expertise with this! I'm running the Debian Stable distribution of Linux, which is pretty behind. Installing the latest version of biblatex and its dependencies makes your example work perfectly -- thank you! Unfortunately, when I try to compile my Thesis, however, I run into problems (I think the utf8x option causes the following error: `! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'ucs'.`) So I can either try to find a workaround (different fontenc option, XeTex etc) or just give up and hope the thesis examiners don't notice!

Comment: @MCS, do you really need the `utf8x` option? I think that `utf8` would do in most cases. If not, switching to XeTeX might be another possibility.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether such an approach meets your requirements, but the [siam.bst](http://etna.mcs.kent.edu/LaTeX/siam.bst) file uses a `last.authors` string to print a line instead of authors' names if they appear consecutively (see e.g. [this example](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aIlKNf1kkX_oJ%3awww.ivo-welch.info/computers/bstfiles/siam.pdf+siam+bst+example&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiOHpWjFpXJZ_JsSVGUlUVKmvoya4ArdDPB6X0RDfnbPxdnTNUad8XEl3-3ltmjZjuasiDUp6MkaHWB3rL4fkQRB86a8w9mmcfZzyDevAMxEg-f5ba_D7V81IlWt5V7RgN4Hiw2&sig=AHIEtbQM6aKcnPcEOAVim5rYyZh3kdamrw)). I assume changing your bst file according to what is done in siam.bst (namely, the `FUNCTION {format.authors}` part), notwithstanding the additions you want to make, should solve your problem.

Comment: `biblatex` doesn't use `.bst` files though, so there is no `.bst` file to modify.

Comment: Oh. My bad, didn't know that.